# Connecting to Azure B2C, with .NET Core from behind a NGINX Proxy

Tags: azure, nginx, asp.net-core, openid, azure-ad-b2c

Almost have this working. Almost.

My set up is that I have an Azure B2C Tenant set up, and some modified [example code](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapp) that I've changed to reflect the Tenant information. This all works fine locally, with a localhost uri.

My remote set up is a Ubuntu 16.01 server, with a Nginx 1.10.0 webserver acting as a reverse proxy to a .NET Core 1.0.4 and all with a LetsEncrypt SSL cert.

The proxy serves .NET projects fine, however when I hit the sign in it takes me over to the B2C login with an incorrect redirect_url.

I'd expect the value to reflect what is in the settings file, "https.sub.host.suffix/signin-oidc" instead I'm getting "http.sub.host.suffix,sub.host.suffix/signin-oidc"

Any ideas or suggestions appreciated!

Comment: There's an issue with the sample, it's not wiring up the Callback path. I'm not 100% sure this is related to your issue or that it will fix it but it's worth a try. https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapp/issues/28

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If NGINX is offloading SSL/TLS and then calling the .NET Core app, check as most probably is doing it through open HTTP (port 80).

You either need to ensure HTTPS all-the-way, or signal an HTTPS scheme to get triggered if HTTP endpoint was called.

As the .NET Core App gets a request through an HTTP endpoint, every URI created by it will keep that same scheme. So, you'll need to force https:// at link building time.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I need to do some more investigation, but it looks like it brings back the return URIs from the tenant and replaces the scheme with the scheme it's running under.

Simply changing the {RedirectContextObject}.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri in OnRedirectToIdentityProvider fixes the problem. Not a long term solution, but fine for a proof of concept.

Just got to get cookies to play nicely with the reverse proxy now.

Comment: brilliant. @DavidFury did you find a proper solution to this issue? thanks