# asp.net core site behind proxy: Azure B2C signin results in correlation failed

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, azure-ad-b2c

I've got a web app that uses Azure B2C sign in.  When I run the site locally, with config set to signin to the Azure B2C tenant, everything works as expected.

I then deploy the site to Azure where I have two webapp siting behind a FrontDoor proxy/load balancing configuration.  I have also tried the same using traffic manager.

When I click on the Sign In link, which should redirect me to the Sign In B2C page, instead, I am redirected back to my site and get an error on the webpage:  **Correlation failed.**

Assuming I have two web apps in the frontdoor configuration, called:

- mywebapp-eastus
- mywebapp-westus

and assuming the public domainname is https://www.mywebapp.com

when i make sign in require, in the response headers of the signin-oidc request, I am seeing this:

```
set-cookie: ARRAffinity=335ad67894a0a02a521f095924a8d7be4f7829a49d21743b7dd9ec8ce66879d7;Path=/;HttpOnly;Domain=mywebapp-eastus.azurewebsites.net
```

where **mywebapp-eastus** is actually an individual web app name.  I would have expected to see the public domain here, not the individual web app that I connected to.

As can be seen from this Chrome dev tool screenshot, the signin-oidc then results in an error after the redirect has occurred:

[image: requests]

I would expect to see this instead:
    ARRAffinity=335ad67894a0a02a521f095924a8d7be4f7829a49d21743b7dd9ec8ce66879d7;Path=/;HttpOnly;Domain=www.mywebapp.com

I don't know if this is the underlying reason for the error.

Here is the code that sets up authentication and cookies:

```
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory = ctx => new ValidationProblemDetailsResult();
        });

            services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
            {
                sharedOptions.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddAzureAdB2C(options => Configuration.Bind(AppSettings.AzureB2CSettings, options))
            .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
            {
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
                options.SlidingExpiration = true;
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = false;
                options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest;
            });
```

**Update**

I have added x-forwarded-proto options with no noticeable effect:

```
        var forwardingOptions = new ForwardedHeadersOptions()
        {
            ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
        };
        forwardingOptions.KnownNetworks.Clear(); 
        forwardingOptions.KnownProxies.Clear();
        app.UseForwardedHeaders(forwardingOptions);
```

I thought i had found a related issue here: [x-forwarded-proto-not-working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43749236/net-core-x-forwarded-proto-not-working)

Any idea how I can resolve this issue?  What options can I set so that the public domain is correctly populated into the response headers.

The web app is running asp.netcore 2.2 on linux (web app for containers).

**Update 2:**

I've added logging to the site.  It shows that there's an underlying error:  **Cookie not found** and **Correlation failed**

> Information {Protocol="HTTP/1.1", Method="POST", ContentType="application/x-www-form-urlencoded", ContentLength=722, Scheme="http", Host="webapp-eastus.azurewebsites.net", PathBase="", Path="/signin-oidc", QueryString="", EventId={Id=1}, SourceContext="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost", RequestId="0HLKC8D934664:00000001", RequestPath="/signin-oidc", CorrelationId=null, ConnectionId="0HLKC8D934664"} "Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://webapp-eastus.azurewebsites.net/signin-oidc application/x-www-form-urlencoded 722"
>   Debug {EventId={Id=1}, SourceContext="Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.HstsMiddleware", RequestId="0HLKC8D934664:00000001", RequestPath="/signin-oidc", CorrelationId=null, ConnectionId="0HLKC8D934664"} The request is insecure. Skipping HSTS header.
>   Debug {EventId={Id=1}, SourceContext="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware", RequestId="0HLKC8D934664:00000001", RequestPath="/signin-oidc", CorrelationId=null, ConnectionId="0HLKC8D934664"} "POST" requests are not supported
>   Debug {EventId={Id=25, Name="RequestBodyStart"}, SourceContext="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel", RequestId="0HLKC8D934664:00000001", RequestPath="/signin-oidc", CorrelationId=null} Connection id ""0HLKC8D934664"", Request id ""0HLKC8D934664:00000001"": started reading request body.
>   Debug {EventId={Id=26, Name="RequestBodyDone"}, SourceContext="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel", RequestId="0HLKC8D934664:00000001", RequestPath="/signin-oidc", CorrelationId=null} Connection id ""0HLKC8D934664"", Request id ""0HLKC8D934664:00000001"": done reading request body.
>   [40m[1m[33mwarn[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler[15]
>         '.AspNetCore.Correlation.OpenIdConnect.2KB8HPHJV3KhB2HCDp3C3b5iPXjcdAQLOrz5-6nGnwY' cookie not found.
>   Warning {EventId={Id=15}, SourceContext="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler", RequestId="0HLKC8D934664:00000001", RequestPath="/signin-oidc", CorrelationId=null, ConnectionId="0HLKC8D934664"} '".AspNetCore.Correlation.OpenIdConnect.2KB8HPHJV3KhB2HCDp3C3b5iPXjcdAQLOrz5-6nGnwY"' **cookie not found**.
>   Information {EventId={Id=4}, SourceContext="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler", RequestId="0HLKC8D934664:00000001", RequestPath="/signin-oidc", CorrelationId=null, ConnectionId="0HLKC8D934664"} Error from RemoteAuthentication: "**Correlation failed.**".
>   Debug {SourceContext="AppBuilderExtensions", RequestId="0HLKC8D934663:00000001", RequestPath="/", CorrelationId=null, ConnectionId="0HLKC8D934663"} Header: "User-Agent": ["Edge Health Probe"]
>   Debug {SourceContext="AppBuilderExtensions", RequestId="0HLKC8D934663:00000001", RequestPath="/", CorrelationId=null, ConnectionId="0HLKC8D934663"} Header: "X-Client-IP": ["1.1.1.1"]
>   Information {ElapsedMilliseconds=12.3269, StatusCode=302, ContentType=null, EventId={Id=2}, SourceContext="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost", RequestId="0HLKC8D934664:00000001", RequestPath="/signin-oidc", CorrelationId=null, ConnectionId="0HLKC8D934664"} "Request finished in 12.3269ms 302 "
>   Debug {EventId={Id=6, Name="ConnectionReadFin"}, SourceContext="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets"} Connection id ""0HLKC8D934664"" received FIN.
>   Debug {EventId={Id=7, Name="ConnectionWriteFin"}, SourceContext="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets"} Connection id ""0HLKC8D934664"" sending FIN because: ""The client closed the connection.""
>   Debug {SourceContext="AppBuilderExtensions", RequestId="0HLKC8D934663:00000001", RequestPath="/", CorrelationId=null, ConnectionId="0HLKC8D934663"} Header: "X-Client-Port": ["63761"]
>   Debug {SourceContext="AppBuilderExtensions", RequestId="0HLKC8D934663:00000001", RequestPath="/", CorrelationId=null, ConnectionId="0HLKC8D934663"} Header: "X-FD-HealthProbe": ["1"]
>   Debug {SourceContext="AppBuilderExtensions", RequestId="0HLKC8D934663:00000001", RequestPath="/", CorrelationId=null, ConnectionId="0HLKC8D934663"} Header: "X-WAWS-Unencoded-URL": ["/"]
>   Debug {SourceContext="AppBuilderExtensions", RequestId="0HLKC8D934663:00000001", RequestPath="/", CorrelationId=null, ConnectionId="0HLKC8D934663"} Header: "CLIENT-IP": ["1.1.1.1:63761"]
>   Debug {SourceContext="AppBuilderExtensions", RequestId="0HLKC8D934663:00000001", RequestPath="/", CorrelationId=null, ConnectionId="0HLKC8D934663"} Header: "X-ARR-LOG-ID": ["5022cb4d-7c63-4a78-ad11-c8474246281d"]
>   Debug {SourceContext="AppBuilderExtensions", RequestId="0HLKC8D934663:00000001", RequestPath="/", CorrelationId=null, ConnectionId="0HLKC8D934663"} Header: "DISGUISED-HOST": ["webapp-eastus.azurewebsites.net"]
>   Debug {SourceContext="AppBuilderExtensions", RequestId="0HLKC8D934663:00000001", RequestPath="/", CorrelationId=null, ConnectionId="0HLKC8D934663"} Header: "X-SITE-DEPLOYMENT-ID": ["webapp-eastus"]
>   Debug {SourceContext="AppBuilderExtensions", RequestId="0HLKC8D934663:00000001", RequestPath="/", CorrelationId=null, ConnectionId="0HLKC8D934663"} Header: "WAS-DEFAULT-HOSTNAME": ["webapp-eastus.azurewebsites.net"]
>   Debug {SourceContext="AppBuilderExtensions", RequestId="0HLKC8D934663:00000001", RequestPath="/", CorrelationId=null, ConnectionId="0HLKC8D934663"} Header: "X-Original-URL": ["/"]
>   Debug {EventId={Id=10, Name="ConnectionDisconnect"}, SourceContext="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel"} Connection id ""0HLKC8D934664"" disconnecting.
>   Debug {EventId={Id=2, Name="ConnectionStop"}, SourceContext="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel"} Connection id ""0HLKC8D934664"" stopped.

Just to be clear, I sticky sessions have been activated on the FrontDoor configuration. I also tried stopping one of the web apps during login to see what the effect was. Same behaviour.  So, I don't think this is a [DataProtection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/web-farm?view=aspnetcore-2.2#data-protection-and-caching) related issue.

**Update 3**

I think I may have found the underlying issue.  I found this error:

> AADB2C90006: The redirect URI 'https://webapp-eastus.azurewebsites.net/signin-oidc' provided in the request is not registered for the client id 'zzzzzzz-2121-4158-b0f8-9d164c95000'.
>   Correlation ID: xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx

When I looked for the X-Forwarded * headers in the request, I found they are missing.  This is even though I have a block of code that looks like this:

```
            services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.ForwardedHeaders =
                ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
        });
```

in ConfigureServices, in Startup.cs

In Configure() I have this:

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseForwardedHeaders();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();

        app.Use((context, next) =>
        {
            context.Request.Scheme = "https";
            return next();
        });

        app.UseSession();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.LogAuthenticationRequests(_loggerFactory);

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

The question now is, why would the X-Forwarded-* headers be missing from requests?

Comment: [more or less the same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44806021/connecting-to-azure-b2c-with-net-core-from-behind-a-nginx-proxy) (I suppose). i think you should configure your application to honour `x-forwared-for` type headers

Comment: thanks for your comment.  can you give a bit of context please?  I don't understand what x-forwared-for type headers can offer, or will resolve. Any idea how I can configure this using asp.net core settings?

Comment: on further inspection, it looks like the ARRAffinity value is correct.  It's stating which host a particular client should be interacting with in a load balanced scenario.  https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps/suggestions/12437064-set-arraffinity-cookie-with-correct-attributes-h

I can ignore that then, something else is wrong with my config.

Comment: Added another update.

Comment: turns out with extra logging, i found another error, which I have updated in the main question under Update 3

Comment: ok, i didnt really use azure front door yet, I wouldnt expect traffic manager to forward those headers, but for afd you can use some test container to get headers that it is forwarding to it. I used this one for tests: https://github.com/mendhak/docker-http-https-echo

Comment: thanks 4c74356b41.  However, i thought the app.UseForwardedHeaders is supposed to result in X-Forwarded * headers in the request, rather than coming back in the response.  I think afd is not the main issue here.  It could be any proxy, and the same issue would arise.  Looks like a coding/config issue rather than proxy related.

Comment: not really, for your app to use those headers - they must be present in the request when it arrives to the app. if  afd doesnt add those to the request, they are not present and your app cant use those

Comment: an update.  I've logged a support request with MS.  Looks like FrontDoor is stripping the AspNetCore prefixed authentication cookies out of the request.  That might explain the Correlation Failed errors.

Comment: Azure AD Application Proxy does not yet support X-Forwarded-Host  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/826463/azure-ad-application-proxy-and-x-forwarded-host-he.html